# Munkres 37.3 maximal set with respect to the countable intersection property.

Tags: general-topology, lindelof-spaces

The author says,

"If $X$ is a set and $\mathbb A$ be the superset consisting of all collections $\mathscr B$ of subsets of $X$ such that $\mathscr A \subset \mathscr B$ and $\mathscr B$ has the countable intersection property.
and $\mathbb A$ has strict partial order by proper inclusion.

If $\mathscr A$ is a collection of subsets of $X$ having the countable intersection property, then there is a collection $\mathscr D$ of subsets of $X$ such that $\mathscr D\subset \mathscr A$ and $\mathscr D$ is maximal with respect to the countable intersection property." is wrong.

Actually this is to try to generalize some lemma which was used to prove Tychonoff theorem. The lemma is
"If $X$ is a set and $\mathscr A$ is a collection of subsets of $X$ having the finite intersection property, then there is a collection $\mathscr D$ of subsets of $X$ such that $\mathscr D\subset \mathscr A$ and $\mathscr D$ is maximal with respect to the finite intersection property."

I guess generalizing this lemma to the countable case fails because the upper bound on $\mathbb B$ which is given subsuperset of $\mathbb A$ that is simply ordered by proper inclusion is not an element of $ \mathbb A$. So we cannot apply Zorn's lemma.

But at this point, I couldn't show my guess is right.

Is my guess right? if not, please give me a little hint so that I could proceed by myself.

Comment: What you quote in the third paragraph as "the lemma" is Lemma 37.1. But is not clear what you want to say with the text between "The author says" and "is wrong". The last part of this text is again Lemma 37.1, but the first part does not make sense.

Comment: @PaulFrost I guess the OP meant to quote exercise 37.3 (c)

Comment: Are you asking for a counterexample or where the proof breaks down?

Comment: @YuiToCheng Yes, I quote 37.3.c. Sorry for disturbing writting... I'd like to know where the proof breaks down.

Comment: The proof doesn't work because it cannot show $\mathbb A$ satisfy the premise of Zorn's Lemma.

Comment: @YuiToCheng Then why is that? is there any counterexample?

Comment: @Grimza It's [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2651891/proof-by-contradiction-product-of-lindelöf-spaces-is-lindelöf) (the second paragraph of Henno Brandsma's answer).